# How to tell R that max/min of empty vector is okay

Tags: r, max, warnings, min

I'm computing the maximum of each of a collection of vectors, and some of these vectors are empty. For my purposes, `max(some.empty.vector)` returning `-Inf` is okay; it is expected, and valid for the further calculations I need to do.

However, I'm getting a warning message, `"no non-missing arguments to max"`. How can I tell R that `max(some.empty.vector)` is not a problem, so there's no need for the warning? I don't want to just ignore the warning message, since there might be warnings coming from other functions, which I wouldn't want to lose track of.

I looked for other questions referring to this error message, and they all appear to be originating from taking the min or max of a vector which is empty unexpectedly, so the problem is the input data, which should not be empty. I'm in a different situation, I have some vectors which I know are empty, and they should be empty, so I can't suppress the warning by ensuring those vectors are nonempty.

Comment: by empty do you mean `NULL` or all values are `NA` because both of those give the same warning and you could use `suppressWarnings` or `tryCatch` or `min(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x)))`

Comment: @rawr Thanks for your interest. For the record, I mean NULL, although the case of all values being NA is also interesting.

Answer (score 2):

We could wrap with `suppressWarnings`

```
suppressWarnings(max(numeric(0), na.rm = TRUE))
[1] -Inf
```

---

Or another option is `max_` from `hablar` which by default have `ignore_na = TRUE`.  It will return `NA` if the length is 0 or `NULL`

```
library(hablar)
max_(numeric())
[1] NA
max_(NULL)
[1] NA
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to avoid `suppressWarnings` because it is a blunt instrument -- it suppresses this warning, and any other warnings that might come out of `min` or `max`. Be that as it may, this looks like a practical approach for the stuff I'm working on.

Comment: @RobertDodier you could use `max_` which doesn't return the `Inf` and `Inf` can have some buggy issues if not prevented

Comment: @RobertDodier yes, the `suppressWarnings` kind of prevents gettng some useful info.  You may also use an `if/else` condition i.e `if(length(v1) > 0) max(v1, na.rm = TRUE) else message("length is 0")`

Comment: Sure, I could write a function to work around the special case, but I was hoping, with no basis in fact, that I could somehow convince `max` that `-Inf` is in just fine.

Comment: @RobertDodier `max` is a primitive function.  So, `body` won't work on it

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to turn this warning off at the source. `max()` is a primitive function, the code throwing the warning is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/summary.c#L963) (`iop` is an integer code that is 2 if a minimum is being computed and 3 if a max is being computed):

```c
    if(empty && (iop == 2 || iop == 3)) {
    if(ans_type == STRSXP) {
        warningcall(call, _("no non-missing arguments, returning NA"));
    } else {
        if(iop == 2)
        warningcall(call, _("no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"));
        else
        warningcall(call, _("no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"));
        ans_type = REALSXP;
    }
    }
```

The answers above are fine, but I would recommend *not* using a generic `suppressWarnings()`, but rather checking for the particular condition you want to be careful about, e.g.

```r
my_max <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {
   L <- list(...)
   if (length(L) == 0 || 
        (na.rm && length(na.omit(unlist(L))) ==0)) return(-Inf)
   return(base::max(..., na.rm = na.rm))
}

my_max()  ## -Inf
my_max(NA, c(NA, NA))
my_max(NA, c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

To be honest I'm not sure there *are* any other warnings that `max()` could produce, but this is best practice.

It is, unfortunately, to detect and suppress a *particular* warning message in R (you can use `tryCatch()` to condition on the text of a particular warning, but this is deprecated because message texts might be changed in a different language/locale setting. You can set up your *own* warnings to have custom classes so that they are easier to detect (see [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling)), but with base-R functions you're stuck with what you're given.

Comment: I agree that writing a function to detect the special case is a workable solution. I was hoping that there would be some way to convince the built-in implementation that the `-Inf` return value is in fact just fine. I gather the answer is no, and that's okay too, I can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new function, `max`, calling `base::max` with `suppressWarnings` wrapped around it.

```
max <- function(...) suppressWarnings(base::max(...))

max(numeric(0))
#[1] -Inf
max(NULL)
#[1] -Inf
```

And the other calls return the expected values.

```
max(1:10)
max(c(1:10, NA))
max(c(1:10, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
max(c("a", "b"))
```

### Note:

Like [GuedesBF says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69320190/how-to-tell-r-that-max-min-of-empty-vector-is-okay/69320404?noredirect=1#comment122522413_69320404), the original function `max` will be masked by the new function below. You will no longer be calling `base::max` but `.GlobalEnv$max` or `globalenv()$max`:

```
globalenv()$max(NULL)
#[1] -Inf
```

If later you want the warning, then you must remember that you have a new function loaded.
A better option might be

```
max2 <- function(..., warnings = TRUE) {
  if(warnings){
    suppressWarnings(base::max(...))
  } else {
    base::max(...)
  }
}

max2(NULL)
max2(NULL, warnings = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice answer, although it should come with a black box warning. it sure handles the task, but the original max() function will be masked. If this warning is desired in downstream analyses, the OP would have to be careful. +1

Comment: @GuedesBF Yes, you are right. I will edit with a warning.

Comment: maybe we could create another function with suppressWarnings as an argument. `my_max <- function(suppress_warnings=FALSE, ...) {if (supress_warnings=TRUE{ suppressWarnings(base::max(...))} else {base::max(...)}}`

Comment: @GuedesBF Done, see the edit. And thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I guess I'm not really in favor of redefining `min` or `max`.